# How to sum amount for each group of account number using BI publisher add in words

Tags: bi-publisher

I have summary pay app, and it has multiple cost codes and I need to sum up the amount charged for each account code 
see example:

```
Cost code1  123-458-111
     Line 1 2000
     Line 2 1000
Cost code2  222-123-222
     Line 3 3000
Cost code3  123-458-121
     Line 4 1500
     Line 5 2500
```

I need to print the result as follow

```
Cost code1  123-458-111  3000
Cost code2  222-123-222  3000
Cost code3  123-458-121  4000
```

I have tried this code but it does not give me the correct result, it just looks to the first line.

```
*for-each BI_ITEM_1   BITEMID_1    <?sum (UGENTTLCMPTODATECA_1[.!=''] )?> end*
```

`BI_Item_1` = account number name.

`BI_ItemID_1` = account actual number.

`UGENTTLCMPTODATECA_1` = total completed to date (the amount charged to the account number )

For each is for the data set and its grouped by `BI_Item_1`

Any suggestion? Your help is much appreciated.

I understand pictures make it easier to visualize but I'm not allowed to upload picture to the post yet! which is weird.

Comment: Have you reviewed the BI Publisher Report Designers Guide?

Comment: @EdHayes3 yes and it does not seem helping, i need to combine sum function with current grouping inside a for each loop

Comment: I just submitted an edit to codify your code here. (its the code sample button with the curly brackets; select your code, and press the button to format). If you can put in the exact XML and RTF coding, using the code sample button, that would be a huge help.

Comment: @EdHayes3 Thanks a lot I figured it out.

Comment: Solution was to use ... for-each BI_ITEM_1 BI_ITEMID_1  <?sum(current-group(), clumn name for amount)?> end-for .... and matter fact you can embed the sum inside dummy element in the rtf file